# Apache request in port 80 redirect to tomcat at 8080

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have successfully pointed Apache http request to point to tomcat 8080. but the issue is the images and css are not getting loaded. It still is looking at port 80. The application is hosted in amazon ec2
My tomcat deployed url :

If I type www.abc.com it successfully redirect to my application and shows the welcome page. but the images are not showing.
    If I include port 8080 in the url the image are showing. eg:

```
www.abc.com:8080/WebApplication/img/xy.jpg

server.xml
 <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />


Config of httpd.conf in apache
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
#<Proxy *>
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from .example.co
ProxyPass / http://www.sabc.com:8080/WebApplication1/
ProxyPass /WebApplication1/img www.abc.com:8080/WebApplication1/img
ProxyPass /WebApplication1/css www.abc.com:8080/WebApplication1/css


ProxyPassReverse /WebApplication1/css www.abc.com:8080/WebApplication1/css
ProxyPass /WebApplication1/img www.abc.com:8080/WebApplication1/img
ProxyPassReverse  / www.abc.com:8080/WebApplication1/
#</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is you shouldn't be required to mention ProxyPass settings if you already have below code.

```
ProxyPass         /   http://www.sabc.com:8080/WebApplication1/
ProxyPassReverse  /   http://www.sabc.com:8080/WebApplication1/
```

Still if there is any requirement to specifically mention it, it seems that code written needs to be rectified for ProxyPass Reverse for images as below.

```
ProxyPass /WebApplication1/img               http://www.sabc.com:8080/WebApplication1/img
ProxyPass /WebApplication1/css               http://www.sabc.com:8080/WebApplication1/css
ProxyPass***Reverse*** /WebApplication1/img  http://www.sabc.com:8080/WebApplication1/img
ProxyPassReverse /WebApplication1/css        http://www.sabc.com:8080/WebApplication1/css
```